# Change Flask static folder name to "assets"

Tags: flask, bootstrap-studio

I am using app "Bootstrap Studio" to build my `html,css`. it always generating the static folder as "assets".

also am using `FLASK`, which always search for static folder as "static". and it is kinda hard to keep renaming the assets folder to be "static".. so  gently . is it possible to change static folder name to : 'assets' in FLASK. ?
to be something like this :

```
run.py
WebFiles/
    index.html
    assets/
          css/
             styles.css
          js/
             main.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate your app via `Flask(static_folder="assets")`

Also see https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/